# Solution to system of nonlinear trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have to solve to solve the system of the following equations in terms of the angles $q_1,q_2,q_3$:

\begin{align}
p_x &= c_1c_{23}l_3-c_1s_2l_2+s_1l_1 \\
p_y &= s_1c_{23}l_3-s_1s_2l_2-l_1c_1 \\
p_z &= -l_3s_{23}-c_2l_2-l_0
\end{align}
where $s_i = \sin(q_1), c_i = \cos(q_i)$ for $i=1,2$ and $c_{23} = \cos(q_2+q_3), s_{23} = \sin(q_2+q_3)$. The terms $p_x,p_y,p_z,l_0,l_1,l_2,l_3$ are considered known.

By using the first two equations I arrived at: $p_y = \frac{s_1p_x-l_1}{c_1}$ for $c_1 \neq 0$ and by raising both sides to the power of $2$ and using the identity $c_1^2+s_1^2=1$, I obtained:
$$ s_1^2(p_x^2+p_y^2)-2l_1p_xs_1 + (l_1^2-p_y^2) = 0 $$
and from the latter I derived acceptable results for the angle $q_1$. I know that in order to solve for the angle $q_3$ I can use the below equation:
$$ c_2c_{23}+s_2s_{23} = c_3 $$
but I need to have come up with the appropriate results for the angles $q_1, q_2$. Now, my problem is finding an expression for the angle $q_2$. I thought I could by doing this:
\begin{align*}
-l_3s_{23} &= p_z+c_2l_2+l_0 \Rightarrow (l_3s_{23})^2= (p_z+c_2l_2+l_0)^2 \\
c_{23}l_3 &=\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}+s_2l_2 \Rightarrow (l_3c_{23})^2 = \Big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}+s_2l_2\Big)^2 
\end{align*}
and then by adding the two later equations and using $c_{23}^2+s_{23}^2=1$, I get:
$$ l_3^2 = (p_z+c_2l_2+l_0)^2 + \Big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}+s_2l_2\Big)^2 \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow l_3^2=(p_z+l_0)^2+2(p_z+l_0)l_2c_2+c_2^2l_2^2 +\big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)^2+2\big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)l_2s_2+s_2^2l_2^2 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow 2l_2(p_z+l_0)c_2+2l_2\big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)s_2 = l_3^2-l_2^2-(p_z+l_0)^2 - \big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)^2 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow (p_z+l_0)c_2 = A - \big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)s_2 $$
where $A = \frac{l_3^2-l_2^2-(p_z+l_0)^2 - \big(\frac{p_x-s_1l_1}{c_1}\big)^2}{2l_2}$. Now, if I raise the last equation to the power of $2$ I end up dealing with a second order equation in terms of $s_2$ which produces no appropriate results for $q_2$ because a negative discriminant appears. I really can't figure out where I am making a mistake and if there is a shorter way to derive an expression for $q_2$.

**EDIT:** Corrected second equation for $p_y$. It is $s_1c_{23}l_3$ instead of $s_2c_{23}l_3$.

Comment: If your system is correct then your first step has wrong result. $s_1 p_x - c_1 p_y=l_1+(s_1-s_2)c_1 c_{23} l_3$

Comment: As a test I used $$\begin{align}
1 &= c_1c_{23}\cdot 3-c_1s_2 \cdot 2+s_1\cdot 1 \\
1 &= s_2c_{23}\cdot 3-s_1s_2\cdot 2-1\cdot c_1 \\
1 &= -3s_{23}-c_2\cdot 2-0
\end{align}$$ in M2 (more generally `R=QQ[px,py,pz,l0,l1,l2,l3]` `S=R[s1,c1,s2,c2,s3,c3,MonomialOrder=>Eliminate 5]` 
`I=ideal(px-(c1*(c2*c3-s2*s3)-c1*s2*l2+s1*l1),py-(s2*(c2*c3-s2*s3)-s1*s2*l2-l1*c1),pz-(-l3*(c2*s3+s2*c3)-c2*l2-l0),c1^2+s1^2-1,c2^2+s2^2-1,c3^2+s3^2-1)`) and got a degree 24 polynomial in $c_3$ with ten real roots all in $(-1,1),$ with $s_3,c_2,s_2,c_1,s_1$ determined by polynomials of the form $N s_3=p_{23}(c_3).$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu you were right. I had written wrongly the second equation regarding $p_y$. Now, I edited and corrected it. Apologies!